# Settings Windows 10 Login Screen background to solid black

Tags: windows-10, display, login

I'm trying to set the login screen background to solid black, suitable (for example) for in a dark room.  I have already used the registry entry (HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Policies/Windows/Personalization/NoLockScreen=1) to disable the lock screen and only show the login screen if, for example, I hit Windows+L.   However, settings wants to use the "accent color" from `Settings -> Colors` and it refuses to allow me to use any color approaching anywhere near black as a background color - for anything less than around 50% brightness it flat out refuses to allow the color, saying "This color is not supported".  As far I remember, I've never seen the accent color used anywhere aside from the Settings app and the login screen, but then again I don't use any windows specific apps.

I thought maybe I could re-enable the lock screen and set it to a picture consisting of solid black, but this unfortunately reminded me that the lock screen and the login screen are two separate things.  The lock screen shows the black background with the time shown in white, but as soon as I hit a key, it again jumps to the login screen with the bright background I do not want.

How can I set the *login* screen to have a solid black background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings within windows 10, search for lock screen options.

Set the picture of the black background that you want.

Enable the "Show lock screen background picture on the sign-in screen" option

Hope that helps

Comment: I had to set NoLockScreen=0 in the registry before opening settings, then I was able to set the background picture.  Then I had to set NoLockScreen=1.  But now it goes straight to the login screen with the black background.  Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know of a suitable picture that we can download?

Comment: Aha!  Download [this](https://eu-browse.startpage.com/av/anon-image?piurl=https%3A%2F%2Ffossbytes.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F09%2FWindows-Black-Screen.png&sp=1616852254Tf6e9feb9ba650a563c4aba953b2d63369cc4a0ce1753a7f6922d4772bb4e7048) and use it